# aws lambda does not return anything when using node-postgres to execute a query

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, node-postgres

I have an async function that uses pg to execute a query for a function. It's not returning anything, I'm not sure if it's the way I call my async function that's the issue. The response_test always returns as an empty json object

```
const pg = require('pg');
const Query = require('pg').Query;
const pool = new pg.Pool();

const response = {...my format for response..}

module.exports.login = (event, context, callback)=> {

     try{

            var client = new pg.Client(conn);
              client.connect();
              var query = "select a_function_that_returns_1_row($1, $2)";
              var params = ['param1', 'param2'];
              var reponse_test = get_token(query, params);

              client.end();

            response.body = JSON.stringify(
                {
                    reponse_test
                }
            )

            callback(null, response);
        } catch(err){
            serverError.body = JSON.stringify({
                error: err
            });
            callback(null, serverError);
        }
}

async function get_token(query, params){
    try {
        const res = await pool.query(query, params);
        return res.rows[0];
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.stack)
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your `get_token` method is async but you are not awaiting it while calling. You also don't need callback. Just make your lambda function async and return the response. Something like this

```
const pg = require("pg");
const Query = require("pg").Query;
const pool = new pg.Pool();

const response = {};

module.exports.login = async event => {

  try {

    const client = new pg.Client(conn);
    client.connect();
    const query = "select a_function_that_returns_1_row($1, $2)";
    const params = ["param1", "param2"];
    const reponse_test = await get_token(query, params);

    client.end();

    response.body = JSON.stringify(
      {
        reponse_test
      }
    );

    return response;
  } catch (err) {
    serverError.body = JSON.stringify({
      "error": err
    });
    return serverError;
  }
};

async function get_token(query, params) {
  try {
    const res = await pool.query(query, params);
    return res.rows[0];
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
  }
}
```